# @Html.Dropdownlist retorna valor nulo

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, dropdown

```
ASP.NET MVC4
```

Estou com um problema de retorno de dados de uma dropdownlist onde a mesma lista corretamente os valores, mas ao escolher algum valor e dar post na página o valor chega como nulo na controller.

meu Dominio  esta assim: **Tabela de Conteúdo**

```html
namespace VelhosAmigos.WebSite.Dominio.Entidade
{
    public class Conteudo
    {
        [Key]
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public int IdConteudo {get; set;}

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Digite um Título")]
        [Display(Name = "Título: ")]
        [StringLength(150, ErrorMessage = "O Título da publicação não pode ter mais que 150 caracteres.")]
        [Description("Teste de descrição")]
        public string Titulo { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Digite um Conteúdo para exibição")]
        [Display(Name = "Conteúdo completo: ")]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string txt_Conteudo { get; set; }

        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Escolha uma categoria")]
        [Display(Name = "Categoria: ")]
        public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
```

E a tabela de Categorias:

```html
namespace VelhosAmigos.WebSite.Dominio.Entidade
{
    public class Categoria
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdCategoria { get; set; }

        public string NomeCategoria { get; set; }

        public int IdSessao { get; set; }

        
    }
}
```

No repositório da Categoria tenho uma lista de todas as categorias:

```html
namespace VelhosAmigos.WebSite.Dominio.Repositorio
{
    public class CategoriasRepositorio
    {
        private readonly EFDbContext _context = new EFDbContext();

        public IEnumerable<Categoria> Categorias
        {
            get { return _context.Categorias; }
        }

        public List<Categoria> retornarTodas()
        {
            var categorias = (from c in _context.Categorias
                              select c).ToList();

            return categorias;
        }
    }
}
```

E no controler, tenho uma `ViewBag` que passa todas as categorias cadastradas no banco para serem usadas como `Dropdownlist` na criação ou alteração de um novo conteúdo.

```html
       public ViewResult Alterar(int IdConteudo)
        {
            _repositorio = new ConteudosRepositorio();
            Conteudo conteudo = _repositorio.Conteudos
                .FirstOrDefault(c => c.IdConteudo == IdConteudo);

            var _categRepositorio = new CategoriasRepositorio().retornarTodas();
            ViewBag.Categorias = _categRepositorio;

          
            return View(conteudo);

        }
```

Na `View` Alterar tenho o `Dropdownlist` que gera os dados certos, só falta acrescentar uma opção vazia no início com a opção de Selecionar uma Categoria que ainda não sei fazer também.

```html
@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.Categoria, new SelectList(@ViewBag.Categorias, "IdCategoria", "NomeCategoria"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

O resultado desse DropdownList está aparentemente correto:

```html
<select name="Categoria" id="Categoria" class="form-control">
  <option value="1">Fique por Dentro</option>
<option value="2">Artigos</option>
</select>
```

Mas ao escolher uma opção e preencher os outros requisitos do formulário e enviar os dados... no `HttpPost` da `controler`:

```html
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Alterar(Conteudo conteudo)
        {
            var _categRepositorio = new CategoriasRepositorio().retornarTodas();
            ViewBag.Categorias = _categRepositorio;


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (conteudo.IdConteudo > 0)
                {
                    TempData["mensagem"] = string.Format("{0} foi alterado com sucesso!", conteudo.Titulo);
                }
                else 
                {
                    TempData["mensagem"] = string.Format("{0} foi cadastrado com sucesso!", conteudo.Titulo);
                }


                _repositorio = new ConteudosRepositorio();
                _repositorio.Salvar(conteudo);

                

                return RedirectToAction("Listar");
            };

            
            return View(conteudo);
        }
```

Está retornando como `NULL` o valor da Categoria. ai retorna pra página com a listagem refeita e o erro abaixo do campo:

```
<span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Categoria" class="field-validation-error">The value '1' is invalid.</span>
```

No `SQL Server`, o campo Categoria está como `int`, e se eu cadastro manualmente no banco a `listView` exibe os conteúdos cadastrados corretamente.

Answer (score 1):

Esse problema acontece porque o MVC não consegue transformar de volta o valor selecionado no Model desejado, você pode simplesmente criar um campo auxiliar no seu model `Conteudo`.

```
//[Required(ErrorMessage = "Escolha uma categoria")]
[Display(Name = "Categoria: ")]
public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }

public string selectedValue { get; set; }
```

E aqui para

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.selectedValue, new SelectList(@ViewBag.Categorias, "IdCategoria", "NomeCategoria"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```